# How to register user into firebase using phone number without OTP with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to register the user with phone number into firebase, but got an exception `PlatformException(error, Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, ortemprary proof., null)`

is it possible to register user only with phone number without any  OTP?

i tried below code

```
 signIn()async{
    AuthCredential credential= PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode
    );
    await  firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user){
       Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
         print('signed in with phone number successful: user -> $user');
    }).catchError((onError){
      print(onError);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the method `.signInWithCredential`(which actually logs-in the user) requires a parameter of type credentials, these credential are either derived by the method `.verifyPhoneNumber` in the `verificationCompleted` case (only in Android, which doesn't send the sms and verify automatically the phone number, care that is not working always and you should always have a UI fallback) or in the `codeSent` case it returns a verificationId and sends the SMS. These two are the one you should pass to the function `PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential`.

In the first case you dont need to call the `PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential` method as you already have a credentials object.